# Gaps Between Aluminium Sign board Theming and External Wall

Tags: flooring

Is gypsum board durable to use for gaps between external side of wall and aluminium theme cladding sign board.

Comment: What is "theme cladding sign board"?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it. You need something that will not swell, rot, wick water, or delaminate even under water exposure. Gypsum board is very susceptible to moisture.